# Convert array of bytes to base64 string using bash

Tags: bash, base64, encode

Currently I'm using `com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding` class and running following command on Scala REPL to encode the array of bytes like this:

```
scala> com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base64().encode(Array.fill(16)((scala.util.Random.nextInt(256) - 128).toByte))
res5: String = zb6fgtoW404V259DLCg5sQ==
```

So far I've created some shell script for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
max_count=16
count=1
while [ "$count" -le $max_count ];
do
  vector[$count]=$((RANDOM%256-128))
  count=$((count+1))
done

echo $(IFS=' '; (echo "${vector[*]}") | base64) | tr -d ' '
```

But I want to create same logic as `BaseEncoding.base64().encode()` method. Is it possible to convert array of bytes to encoded base64 string on Bash?

Comment: Using Bash for this is unusually ill-advised but piping to `base64` obviously trivially accomplishes this. Putting the bytes in an array is wacky but `printf '%s' "${array[@]}"` trivially prints the bytes back out.

Comment: What is not working with the code you posted?

Comment: The problem is my code converts string not array of bytes, so when I run First code above with `Array(-62, 20, -56, -91, -122, 74, 77, -38, 83, -110, -77, -53, -110, -114, -72, -57)` the result is `whTIpYZKTdpTkrPLko64xw==`, but my scripts result is `LTYyLDIwLC01NiwtOTEsLTEyMiw3NCw3NywtMzgsODMsLTExMCwtNzcsLTUzLC0xMTAsLTExNCwtNzIsLTU3Cg=="` . So they are not same.